# How to overwrite sfConfig setting in functional lime test in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

My Problem is the following i wanted to test some functionality that depended on a certain setting in the sfConfig.
Proposed the setting is `app_foo` and its default is `false`.

The "standard" way to test is like:

```
$browser = new sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());

$browser->
  get('/path_to/index')->
  ...
  end();
```

BUT it does not work to change the setting like

```
sfConfig::set('app_foo', true);
$browser = new sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sfConfig cannot be overwritten in the test because the sfConfig is reset on the next request.

BUT a field named 'rawConfiguration' in the browser instance is added to the sfConfig for the request. So the solution is to set this array:

```
$browserEngine = new sfBrowser();
$browser = new sfTestFunctional($browserEngine);
// overwrite an sfConfig parameter in the browser context
$browserEngine->rawConfiguration = array_merge($browserEngine->rawConfiguration, array('app_foo' => true));
```

Then the action knows the `sfConfig::get('app_foo')` with the value true.

Comment: This is quite appealing... However, I cannot get it through: "PHP Notice:  Undefined property: sfBrowser::$rawConfiguration". Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

The samura answer is nice, you also have to know that config files are environement aware so you can do that in your app.yml:

```
all:
  my_setting: "super"

test:
  my_setting: "awesome"
```

This is also working on the database.yml file, allowing you to run functionnal tests in another database

Comment: yes i know, but i want to test different settings in 1 environment, and then it would be too much work to duplicate whole environent only for testing 1 different setting. But thanks and it's related